# Issues when using a library project in android

Tags: android, android-library

I have developed a Project. it is working fine. so i want to use this project as a library for some other project. so i have created this project as a library. Later i have created new Application and added this library project to my new Application Project. then i run the app .
suddenly the previous screen in the activity stack is finishing automatically. i am not getting why this is Happening. Any one have the idea about this issue , Please suggest me

Comment: Check your logcat and get a precise error, then come back and ask a precise question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is added as a library project.
You still need to add the activities that you are calling/using(from the library project) in your new projects AndroidManifest.xml

Though I must say, you should consider showing your logcat and calling code.

Comment: Thank you for Reply. i have added in manifest. the forward flow of App is ok. but when i click Back  of any Screen. i am coming out of the application. there are no previous screens in the stack

Comment: logcat is not giving any exception. nothing it is giving

Comment: yes i got it. beacuase of manifest file only. i am getting that problem. thanku very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you set reference to your project?
Rightclick on your project-properties-android-islibrary mark it and add

Answer (score 0):

android:noHistory="true".
beacause of this attribute. stack history was removed. by removing this attribute it working fine