# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY on android 2.3.4

Tags: android, google-maps

My android is W806 with MIUI system(andrid 2.3.4， could be downloaded at

```
http://119.147.150.88/gdown_group321/M00/01/BB/d5OWWE-TiE0AAAAABFRc6HZ-Izc1688998/MIUI_W806_updateEX.zip?k=rscjHEFnZBVxNvfDqVP3Iw&t=1355119512&u=712526008-27587528-bjpdc2a8&s=51200&file=MIUI_W806_updateEX.zip
```

）
I follow this example: http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/using-google-maps-in-android-development-tutorial-part-1/, I have chosen Google API of 2.3.3 downloaded from SDK manager. But I got the problem Installation error: `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`.

I try to search solutions in google and stackoverflow, but no one fits me...I have some logcat, and here it is:

```
12-10 16:38:19.820: W/dalvikvm(5906): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/googlemapapp/GooglemapsActivity; (463)
12-10 16:38:19.820: W/dalvikvm(5906): Link of class 'Lcom/example/googlemapapp/GooglemapsActivity;' failed
12-10 16:38:19.820: D/AndroidRuntime(5906): Shutting down VM
12-10 16:38:19.820: W/dalvikvm(5906): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4011b560)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapapp/com.example.googlemapapp.GooglemapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.googlemapapp.GooglemapsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.googlemapapp-1.apk]
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3684)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.googlemapapp.GooglemapsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.googlemapapp-1.apk]
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
12-10 16:38:19.830: E/AndroidRuntime(5906):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: in which folder you have add your libs? name of your folder :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some information in your android project files and/or AndroidManifest.xml ?

Try and look at my earlier answer to a somewhat similar answers:

[1. Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393327/issues-when-using-a-library-project-in-android/13393472#13393472)
[2. Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579425/error-when-calling-pure-java-code-separate-project-from-android-in-eclipse/11579711#11579711)